# Unity Integration in native mobile (iOS / Android ) application

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to integrate unity game in mobile Application on specific button action in App, I already integrate it in Android, in Android I need to open specific activity on Button Action. But in iOS, there need to lots of stuff work and manage to initialize unityView in appdelegate, in iOS is there specific way to open view controller for playing unity game.

I follow below references for integrate unity game in an iOS application,
- https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5

Comment: where is the question or the problem ?

Comment: I need to do lots of work, I need to find easier ways to integrate in iOS.